Failed to get FCM Token in React native production build (TV Application) [react-native-firebase]
I tried to get the FCM token in react native with the help of the "@react-native-firebase/messaging" version ^19.2.2.
const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();

It is working fine in the debug build i mean i have run the build in the android studio [TV] emulator. It is fine and giving me the unique fcm token. But when i try to get the token after the build it gives me the error. I have used the following line to know that the permission is given or not.
const authorized = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();

It gives me the positive (1) in emulator and in the production build false (0). So i thought get the permission will solve this issue. When i search for the solution i got the code to get the permission.
const authorized = await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();

But even with it it don't  give me the permission. Even i don't get the notification for getting the permission. And also i have added the "implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0')" in the build.gradle in the "android/app". Is there i need anymore to be added anything in it.
Note:- I'm looking for the solution for react native for android television.
I'm looking for the solution for react native for android television.

Did you declare the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in your manifest?

Yes i have added the  POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in manifest
